# CoutputCache yii i want to cache a different versions of a page and use them depending on a condition

Tags: caching, yii

i am trying to use CoutputCache to cache a different versions of the same action, and keep all the version in cache and use any of them depending on a condition.
any help?

Comment: Elaborate, give more details and example code. How do you determine the different output of the action (when does it show version A or version B)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get params in the varyByParam parameter to generate a different version of each action.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array( 
            array(
                'COutputCache + myAction',
                'duration'=>1,
                'varyByParam'=>array('my_get_param'),
            ),


    );
}
```

where myAction is the route name of your controller method, such as actionMyAction()

Then attach various get params to your request and each unique request will be cached separately.